# leaflet .bindPopup() not working after page change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am  working on leaflet map and showing markers on it. on click of marker I am opening the popup and on click of that navigating it to another page, this all works fine but when I click back from the navigated page to map then the `.bindPopup()` is not working and I am not able to open the popup again.

here is my code:

```
var marker = leaflet.circleMarker([marker.latitude, marker.longitude], { renderer, radius: 8, weight: 1, color: '#fff', fillColor: markerColor, fillOpacity: 1 })
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup(marker.id + '<br/>' + marker.status + '<br/>');

    marker.on('click', (e) => {
      var popup = e.target.getPopup();
      this.issueServiceProvider.getIssue(marker.id, false).subscribe((result) => {
        var div = leaflet.DomUtil.create('div', 'command');
        div.innerHTML = marker.id + '<br/>' + marker.status + '<br/>' + result.description + '<br/><a id = "command">More Details</a> <br/>';
        popup.setContent(div);
        leaflet.DomEvent.addListener(div, 'click', () => {
          this.navCtrl.push(Constants.Page.IssueDetails, { markerId: marker.id }, Constants.Animation['TransitionForward']);
        });
      }, (err) => {
        console.error('Error' + err);
      });
    });
```

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This popup works, but does not reference your specific function.  Try this and then add your function call once the basic setup is complete.

```
var marker = leaflet.circleMarker([39, -105], { radius: 8, weight: 1, color: "#274FCA", fillOpacity: 1 })
  .addTo(map)
  .bindPopup(this.id + '<br/>' + this.status + '<br/>');

marker.on('click', (e) => { 
    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'command');
    div.innerHTML = 'marker.id' + '<br/>' + 'marker.status' + '<br/>' + 'result.description' + '<br/><a id = "command">More Details</a> <br/>';
    popup.setContent(div);
    leaflet.DomEvent.addListener(div, 'click', () => {
        this.navCtrl.push(Constants.Page.IssueDetails, { markerId: marker.id }, Constants.Animation['TransitionForward']);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes I tried with your option as well. still not working.  @zakariah1